# OS GUI development learning:How to find the best recources to learn the GUI development for OS developing?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, x11, systems-programming

There has some best resources to learn the OS GUI development?For example,books or documents or other things in respect of this fact.I want to read the books which are related to Unix:X Window System or C video programming and other things such as.Someone can guide me to learn the OS GUI development? Especially,guide to read a good book or point to something how should I begin for this.